# Is there a way to have Photoshop NOT save print settings between prints?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I work at a retail print shop and use photoshop often to print documents.

I've noticed ever since we upgraded to CS6, PS will save the print settings between unrelated files. Eg: I set the print settings to print 30 copies from a certain tray in our printer and grayscale. I quit the program. Then the next time I open a completely different customer file, hit print, the same settings (number of copies and all) are still set to print that document.

This seems like a good idea, but it makes for a lot of wasted paper when we are expecting to hit print and it go to the default settings.

I'm using a Windows 7 installed PC, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Seems to me this is far more tech support than design related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In Version CS6, when you hold down the <kbd>space bar</kbd> when selecting **File >
>   Print**, the previous print settings for the document will be **ignored**.
>
> Having this capability is useful if you have a file with corrupted
>   print settings. This command enables you to specify the print settings
>   from scratch.

[Search source](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-set-printing-options-in-photoshop-cs6.html)

Answer (score 2):

Why not try using an action or script to [run your print job](http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2011/08/automating-printing-with-actions-and-scripts.html)? You could have one-click functionality for any combination of print jobs.

I know this doesn't 'solve' the specific issue, but removes it with a superior and customized workflow. In addition to time saved, it would also remove user error as the print settings are preset in the script.